# How to check if a field of a spring form is disabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

I need to know if the field of the spring form is disabled or not. What will I do to do this?

```
var isDisabled = $('#dateUsed').prop('disabled');
var isDisabled = document.getElementById('dateUsed').disabled;
```

I tried these codes to check if it's disabled but it returns false even though it is disabled.

Code:

The field:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                      <form:label path="materialUsed.dateUsed">Date Used</form:label> <star id="dateUsedStar" class="hidden" >*</star>
                      <form:input path="materialUsed.dateUsed" type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker" id="dateUsed" disabled="true"/>
              </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

In my Javascript:

```
var isDisabled = $('#dateUsed').prop('disabled');
var isDisabled = document.getElementById('dateUsed').disabled;
alert(isDisabled);
```

I expect the output to be true since it is disabled in the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can test this my using the **"is" method** ; which will return a boolean

```
$('#dateUsed').is(':disabled');
console.log($('#dateUsed').is(':disabled')) // True
```

On a personal Note its rather better to use **readonly="true"** in your form fields
rather than the **disabled** property.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the format of the HTML you are using.

```
<form:label path="materialUsed.dateUsed">Date Used</form:label> <star id="dateUsedStar" class="hidden" >*</star>
<form:input path="materialUsed.dateUsed" type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker" id="dateUsed" disabled="true"/>
```

I don't think this is valid HTML.

Try this HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label path="materialUsed.dateUsed">Date Used</label> <star id="dateUsedStar" class="hidden" >*</star>
            <input path="materialUsed.dateUsed" type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker" id="dateUsed" disabled="true"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var isDisabled = $('#dateUsed').prop('disabled');
    alert(isDisabled);
});
```

Here is a demonstration
https://jsfiddle.net/markou/mo7r5anq/8/

This works, and you get true.

If you replace this HTML with the HTML you have above will get undefined.